# Flutter loader not visible (Test flight and build android apk)

Tags: flutter, widget, apk, testflight, loader

> When I build my code locally on iOS and Android my loader work nice, but when I send my app to Test Flight loader become not visible and sane issue in Android when I build apk.

My loader code using [flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit)

```
class LoadingPage {
  static Widget loadingPage() {
    const spinkit = SpinKitChasingDots(
      color: AppColor.orangeColor,
      size: 50,
    );
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: AppColor.transparent,
        child: spinkit,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use latest version flutter_spinkit, and also I update all dependencies which I have.